# expect script's puts is printing on wrong position

Tags: tcl, expect, puts

I am using below expect script on a linux machine, to run command(s) on a remote device via ssh, and printing its output back on the linux machine where script ran.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set fp [open "~/passwfile" r]
set data [read $fp]

set host [lindex $argv 0];

set prompt [lindex $argv 1];

set timeout 10

spawn ssh $host
while {1} {
  expect \
  {
    "*(yes/no)? "      {send "yes\r"}
    "*assword:"        {send "$data\r"}
    "*$host*$prompt"   {break}
    timeout            {exit 2}
    eof                {puts "\rBreaking - EOF\r"; exit 1}
  }
}

for {set i 2} {$i <= [llength $argv]} {incr i 1} {
  if {$i < [llength $argv]} {puts "";puts ""; puts "\r## command [expr {$i - 1}] start ##"}
  send "\r"
  expect \
  {
    "*$host*$prompt"   {send "[lindex $argv $i]\r"}
    timeout            {exit 4}
    eof                {puts "\rBreaking - EOF\r"; exit 3}
  }

  while {1} {
    expect \
    {
      "*$host*$prompt"   {break}
      "Press <SPACE> to continue or <Q> to quit:" {send " "}
      "(more"          {send " "}
      "More-"          {send " "}
      "ESC->exit"      {send "\x1b\r"}
      timeout          {exit 4}
      eof              {puts "\rBreaking - EOF\r"; exit 3}
    }
  }
  if {$i < [llength $argv]} {puts "\r## command [expr {$i - 1}] finish ##"}
}

send "exit\r"
puts ""

exit 0
```

It takes hostname, prompt character and command(s), as parameters.

Example

```
$ ./expectssh bcr03a.dal10 "#" "sh int et1/8"
```

I need each command's output to be printed between its own start and finish lines. For above example this is the expected output:

```
.
.
.
bcr03a.dal10# 

## command 1 start ##

bcr03a.dal10# sh int et1/8
Ethernet1/8 is up
admin state is up, Dedicated Interface
  Belongs to Po106
  Hardware: 40000/100000 Ethernet, address: 70d3.7962.898c (bia 70d3.7962.898c)
  MTU 9216 bytes, BW 100000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec
  reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, medium is broadcast
  Port mode is trunk
  full-duplex, 100 Gb/s, media type is 100G
  Beacon is turned off
  Auto-Negotiation is turned off
  Input flow-control is off, output flow-control is off
  Auto-mdix is turned off
  Rate mode is dedicated
  Switchport monitor is off 
  EtherType is 0x8100 
  EEE (efficient-ethernet) : n/a
    admin fec state is auto, oper fec state is cl91
  Last link flapped 59week(s) 4day(s)
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  2 interface resets
  Load-Interval #1: 30 seconds
    30 seconds input rate 249767432 bits/sec, 25786 packets/sec
    30 seconds output rate 178732832 bits/sec, 25343 packets/sec
    input rate 249.77 Mbps, 25.79 Kpps; output rate 178.73 Mbps, 25.34 Kpps
  Load-Interval #2: 5 minute (300 seconds)
    300 seconds input rate 335318184 bits/sec, 24583 packets/sec
    300 seconds output rate 197360256 bits/sec, 25510 packets/sec
    input rate 335.32 Mbps, 24.58 Kpps; output rate 197.36 Mbps, 25.51 Kpps
  RX
    455840060118 unicast packets  436446550 multicast packets  87396954 broadcast packets
    456363082369 input packets  585827288945618 bytes
    37037870002 jumbo packets  0 storm suppression packets
    0 runts  0 giants  0 CRC/FCS  0 no buffer
    0 input error  0 short frame  0 overrun   0 underrun  0 ignored
    0 watchdog  0 bad etype drop  0 bad proto drop  0 if down drop
    0 input with dribble  0 input discard
    0 Rx pause
  TX
    431362512003 unicast packets  2143469193 multicast packets  555138516 broadcast packets
    434061134995 output packets  489379806337887 bytes
    19176210395 jumbo packets
    0 output error  0 collision  0 deferred  0 late collision
    0 lost carrier  0 no carrier  0 babble  0 output discard
    0 Tx pause

bcr03a.dal10#
## command 1 finish ##
```

Interesting part is I am receiving this expected output sometimes, but some other times the "## command 1 finish ##" line is being printed earlier. Usually 2 or 3 lines above the "RX" line, on above expected output snippet.

Can you please help me to fix this random behavior?

Comment: I don't think this will fix your problem… but you can ask an `expect` to keep waiting from inside a response script using `exp_continue`. This means you don't need to wrap it in `while 1`.

Comment: Unfortunately you showed the output for a successful case rather than a failing one. Your code looks for '$host*$prompt' (the leading * is meaningless) and you see a match just before "RX". That's near where there's a "#" (your prompt) in the output. Apparently, in the failing case, $host has also appeared somewhere. Remove that leading * and dump $expect(0,string) somewhere at the end or your code to see exactly what it matched. Alternatively use `exp_internal 1` or run expect with the -d option to figure out what happens.